# calendar control for ipad sdk

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, sdk, calendar

I'm using 4.2 sdk version.

Is there any control for a calendar view similar to the ipads calendar app? im using [Kal](http://klazuka.tumblr.com/post/315035813/kal-a-calendar-component-for-the-iphone) on the iphone, but as it seems it is not available as ipad version. Is there anything for the ipad yet?

If use Kal it is not equivalent to ipad. See Sample image below

[image]

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did it. I simply modified some codes manually, I used Kal project. Finally i got the correct solution.

See my Calendar image in iPad now

[image]

Comment: @akk could you update your answer and tell me how can you fix it, please?

Comment: How to write event (UILabel/UIImageView) in grid view on particular box insted of 'dot'? can you please tell me it is possible or not..?? if yes then how..?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the same for iPad too.But you will have to set the frame of KalView again for iPad device if detected.So you will have two different frames for iPhone and  iPad.

One thing more you have a method in your KalView class.Go through it you will see a method named :

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame delegate:(id<KalViewDelegate>)theDelegate logic:     (KalLogic *)theLogic
{
 //change the size for content view
}
```

Comment: KLCalendarView is not in Kal project. where is this placed

Comment: you will have to change the frame property for each view that is initially set for iPhone only if you intend to use the same Kal.If you want to use another framework then tapku is an alternative.Otherwise you will have to do some manual work.

Comment: i got this line - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame logic:(CalendarLogic *)aLogic;   ....... what to do after that? if i want to do #define kCalendarDayWidth 46.0f
#define kCalendarDayHeight 44.0f to #define ipadkCalendarDayWidth 46.0f
#define ipadkCalendarDayHeight 44.0f, then the date is not clickable